# Printing Cookie domain in RequestsCookieJar using Python 3

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, pickle

I'm working with Python requests module and have ran into an issue I can't seem to resolve. I'm relatively new to requests, but even with googling/documentation I have hit a wall.

I am trying to get a link (or "domain") from a specific cookie that is in the response of a GET request i've made. I can only seem to print the cookie, and not the domain. Explanation below:

**Code (See comments):**

```
import pickle
import requests
import time

r = requests.post('https://example.com/AddToCartURL')
print("----------------------------------------")
cookies = r.cookies #prints all cookies
print(r.cookies)
time.sleep(3)

# Code below will now use cookies and do a GET request to checkout URL

r = requests.get("https://example.com/checkout", cookies=cookies)
print("HEADERS")
time.sleep(1)
print(r.headers)
print("---------")
print("Cookie")
print(r.cookies)
print("---------") # THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS :
print(r.cookies['checkout']) # This prints the cookie itself
print(r.cookies['checkout']['domain'])
```

**outputs & issues:**

So here are my issues:

**#1 - The cookieJar cookie is shown like so when I print r.cookies:**

```
<Cookie checkout=r3jk43nb42knj32--fjnk3jk2jkn2323njk for www.example.com/checkout/url>
```

And when I print(r.cookies['checkout']) I get the cookie, obviously:

r3jk43nb42knj32--fjnk3jk2jkn2323njk

Well what I'm trying to do here, essentially, is get the domain from it, which I try to do as:

print(r.cookies['checkout']['domain'])

getting the response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/Main.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(r.cookies['checkout']['domain'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Which is something you'll find from a quick google search. Documentation wise I wasn't able to find a clear answer, probably because I'm still bad at searching. I tried the obvious of using an integer, presuming they're referencing indexing. However, this prints a single character of the cookie itself.

What i'm trying to print, specifically, is example.com/checkout/url from the cookie above. I'm trying to interact with it to continue my code on through the checkout process.

**This is an example of the full cookie jar:** (called by print(r.cookies))

```
        <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie random_other_cookie= 3j32fj302fj023jfi for example.com/checkoutURL>, <Cookie checkout=r3jk43nb42knj32--fjnk3jk2jkn2323njk for example.com/checkoutURL>]>
```

**--------------------------------**

**#2 - Am I tackling this the wrong way?**

Little more background information, the GET request above gives a response of 301. Permanently moved. I am 99% sure that the URL that I end up at (at least, front end wise) is the URL I need/the same URL as in the cookie above.

My question is should I not be trying to grab the domain from the cookie, and instead somehow try to grab the redirection URL?

(aka the URL that the request ends up at, not the original url https://example.com/checkout)

**------------------------------------**

**I hope I outlined my issues well enough. This is my first post on StackOverflow after months of lurking around for answers.**

**Thank you.**